# Действие на закрытом файле. Закрывается программа после выполнения условия

Tags: python, многопоточность, файлы, обработка-ошибок

Глупый конечно вопрос, но уже не знаю, что делать.

Есть функция, которая работает в постоянном цикла. Читая файл, создаём условие. Возникает ошибка, **ПОСЛЕ** выполнения кода:

```
> Игрок Thor выиграл EssenceLegendary:6 ----- РЕЗУЛЬТАТ.

ОШИБКА
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-1' coro=<REWARD_COUNT() done, defined at c:..\basic.py:362> exception=ValueError('I/O operation on closed file.')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:...\basic.py", line 369, in REWARD_COUNT
    line = f.readline()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

```
    async def REWARD_COUNT():
        while True:
            with open(file, encoding='utf-8', mode='rt') as f:
                f.seek(0,2)
                while True:
                    line = f.readline()
                    if (re.search(РЕГУЛЯРНОЕ ВЫРАЖЕНИЕ, line)):
                        winner = re.search(REWARD_EVENT, line).group(1)
                        prize = re.search(REWARD_EVENT, line).group(2)
                        count = re.search(REWARD_EVENT, line).group(3)
                       
                        print(f"{curtime} > Игрок {winner} выиграл {prize}:{count}")

                    await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
```

Задержка уже стоит, но всё равно ругается:

```
f.seek(0,2)
await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: Вообще `f.seek(0,2)` перемещает указатель в конец файла. Что вы хотите прочитать из конца файла? Хотя ошибку это не объясняет, но всё-таки.

Comment: У вас чтение в бесконечном цикле. Похоже, что при остановке программы файлы закрываются (рантаймом питона?) до того как останавливается цикл  обработки. Сделайте корректную остановку цикла.